# How to transform plist file to csv file ? (XCODE)

Tags: xcode, csv, plist

Can i found a class to transform a plist file (nsdictionnary with string) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such generic solution.

A plist, by it's nature, is a **hierarchical** format.

A csv file, by contrast, is a **tabular** format.

Any conversion between the two will be highly specialised, although generally speaking, you can convert tabular data formats to a hierachical format, but the conversion will be very inefficient.  The reverse, however, is not generally possible in most situations.

For an NSDictionary, however, a conversion is possible, say, with a CSV file with a "Keys" column and a "Values" column, if the keys and values are both very primitive types (such as a string), but this is a very, very small subset of what plists can contain.

Answer (score 1):

There is a ruby gem for this that can be found here:

https://rubygems.org/gems/csv_to_plist

You can download it by running

```
$ gem install csv_to_plist
```

Then you will be able to run

```
$ csv_to_plist my_file.csv
```